# XSSFCell causing lock while setting value when running with huge data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am writing a huge data to Excel sheet. I am using XSSFWorkbook for excel creation.

For 20,000 rows the excel write is fine. But when I try to write a data of more than 1 Million ,the excel sheet is not coming out for more than 3 hours.
When I analyzed `jstack`, I found that there is a lock which is getting created while

```
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell( colNum );
cell.setCellValue( value );
```

setting value to the cell,

The below are the `jstacks`,

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize(Saver.java:1700)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.preEmit(Saver.java:1303)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emit(Saver.java:1190)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emitElement(Saver.java:962)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.processElement(Saver.java:476)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.process(Saver.java:307)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.saveToString(Saver.java:1864)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._xmlText(Cursor.java:546)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.xmlText(Cursor.java:2436)
        **- locked <0x000000076354cdc0> (a org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale)**
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.xmlText(XmlObjectBase.java:1500)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getKey(SharedStringsTable.java:134)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.addEntry(SharedStringsTable.java:180)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:350)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:320)
```

---

How can we handle this.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778630/apache-poi-sxssf-and-xssf
maybe try using  SXSSF when writing instead of XSSF, it handles large files better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SXSSFWorkbook might be a good solution (comment above) - if you want to use XSSFWorkbook you could use an XSSFFactory that provides a SharedStringsTable better suited to your needs (see your stacktrace and it is the SharedStringsTable that is causing the locking)

[XSSFWorkbook Constructor](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.java#L249) that takes an XSSFFactory instance as input

[Custom XSSFFactory example](https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-shared-strings/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/pjfanning/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFFactory.java) that creates a custom SharedStringsTable. This one uses a temp file for the shared strings data but you could modify it to keep the data in a HashMap.

Comment: Thanks PJ Fanning .. it worked.
I used SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook( 10000 );
and all XSSF to SXSSF

Comment: I am facing an exception when I try to download data of more than 1 lakh with SXSSF.

Posted here!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563035/sxssf-causing-attempting-to-write-a-row23237-in-the-range-0-23272-that-is-al