# SXSSF causing Attempting to write a row[23237] in the range [0,23272] that is already written to disk

Tags: java, sxssf

I am creating an excel sheet of more than 100k rows.
I have used SXSSF, since I am handling huge data

```
 SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook( 10000 );
```

keeping 10 000 rows in cache.

But I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[23237] in the range [0,23272] that is already written to disk. 
>           at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.createRow(SXSSFSheet.java:111)

I have tried increasing the cache rows to 50 000:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook( 50000 );
```

But still getting same exception.

In addition to that I have tried the other way of flushing the rows manually like,

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook( -1 ); // which will store unlimeted rows in cache
sheet.flushRows();
```

even this was causing the similar exception!

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[22708] in the range [0,22719] that is already written to disk.

Not sure what is wrong with **23237** th row where this exception occurs!
Despite giving the number of rows of more than 50000 in the cache.

Comment: SXSSFWorkbook is best used with a small cache, eg 10 or 100 rows.